# SSH with Perl using file handles, not Net::SSH

Tags: perl, file-io, ssh, cpan

Before I ask the question:

I can not use cpan module Net::SSH, I want to but can not, no amount of begging will change this fact

I need to be able to open an SSH connection, keep it open, and read from it's stdout and write to its stdin.  My approach thus far has been to open it in a pipe, but I have not been able to advance past this, it dies straight away.

That's what I have in mind, I understand this causes a fork to occur.  I've written code accordingly for this fork (or so I think).

Below is a skeleton of what I want, I just need the system to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use warnings;

$| = 1;

$pid = open (SSH,"| ssh user\@host");

if(defined($pid)){
    if(!$pid){
        #child
        while(<>){
            print;
        }
    }else{
        select SSH;
        $| = 1;

        select STDIN;

        #parent
        while(<>){
            print SSH $_;
            while(<SSH>){
                print;
            }
        }
    close(SSH);
    }
}
```

I know, from what it looks like, I'm trying to recreate "system('ssh user@host')," that is not my *end* goal, but knowing how to do that would bring me much closer to the end goal.

Basically, I need a file handle to an open ssh connection where I can read from it the output and write to it input (not necessarily straight from my program's STDIN, anything I want, variables, yada yada)

This includes password input.

I know about key pairs, part of the end goal involves making key pairs, but the connection needs to happen regardless of their existence, and if they do not exist it's part of my plan to make them exist.

Comment: Please read [But I can't use CPAN!](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/) -- your problem should be shifted towards getting Net::SSH to run, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thos kind of connection, through a script, aren't more confortable with a UI?
Does perl support UI or only python does?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $pid = open my $SSH, '-|', 'ssh user@example.com' // die $!;

if ($pid) {
    while( <$SSH> ) {
        print $_;
    }
}
else {
    while( <> ) {
        print $SSH $_;
    }
}

close $SSH or die $!;
```

Comment: Works with a password prompt or not?

Comment: So? In parent process (`$pid` defined), read and print from ssh server.  In child process (`$pid` not defined), read from STDIN and print to ssh server.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Pedro Silva: the child process runs the `ssh` command, not your Perl code. And the way you call ssh is also broken. Just try it!

Comment: @salva: I don't see your point.  What do you mean the child process runs the ssh command?  The ssh command is run when you call open.  The child process literally reads what the user types at the prompt, and echoes it to the ssh server pointed to by the `$SSH` handle.  And I *have* run the command. It works.

Comment: @Pedro Silva: in your code, $pid is never 0 (unless some error happens) and so the code inside the `else` block never runs. It just happens that the `ssh` command stdin stream gets attached to your console because of the way you run it.

Comment: `perldoc -f open`: `If you open a pipe on the command "-" (that is, specify either "|-" or "-|" with the one- or two-argument forms of "open"), an implicit
               "fork" is done, so "open" returns twice: in the parent process it returns the pid of the child process, and in the child process it returns
               (a defined) 0.  Use "defined($pid)" or "//" to determine whether the open was successful.`

Comment: @Pedro Silva: NO, the child process execs the given command and never returns control to the Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using autossh and setting up port forwarding from a local port using ssh's -L switch, then just connecting to the local port.  This enormously simplifies your programming task at the cost of some minimal setup.

Automatically making key pairs is a really bad idea; they should be set up ahead of time.  Somehow automating that is just asking for security problems.

If you really need to deal with ssh and password prompts, [Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect) is the old-school way of doing that.  I'm not sure what the cool kids are using nowadays.  Update: I'd forgotten but there's a pure perl [Net::SSH::Expect](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aExpect) module that manages the ssh program for you; you probably want to use it or copiously borrow from it.

Comment: I am aware of the security problems inherent in automating key pairs...

it was not my idea, but I was told that the script I'm trying to write should require no human intervention.

Comment: `Net::SSH::Expect` is not reliable, do not use it!

Comment: @salva: "not reliable" is kind of vague; do you have a link?

Comment: @ysth: yes, read the [souce code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BNEGRAO/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pm), specifically the code for `exec` and `read_all` subs. It just uses timeouts to detect when some command is done. It will fail for commands that do not respond immediately or in case of some transitory network problem. Or if you try to use a bigger `$timeout`, it will become very slow.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that if you have to use a module that places extra layers between your code and the actual actions, your error handling is going to suffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) or [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2). For instance:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
my ($in, $out, $pid) = $ssh->open2($remote_cmd);
```

Otherwise, use IPC::Open2 to open a bidirectional comunication:

```
use IPC::Open2 qw(open2);
my $pid = open2(my $in, my $out, $ssh_cmd);
```

Or for a more elaborated and complex implementation that also supports password authentication (via [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect)), take a look at the source code for [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Unix](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SALVA/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.69/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Backend/Unix.pm)::_open4

Answer (score 0):

It's too complicated to detail here, but using ssh master connection (via ControlMaster) is an alternative to using OpenSSH.  Once established, all subsequent SSH connections,regardless of method (including by open $SSH '|-' 'ssh user@host "command"'), are multiplexed through the master without the need for reauthorization and without overhead of establishing new SSH each time.  To a degree, this is how OpenSSH works.

Unfortunately, the method I'm suggest is not available in native Microsoft Windows environment.